# Unity Application.Quit() doesn't work

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

In the update, I have set up a counter so that after 140 frames, Unity will quit the game. But this quit command doesn't quit and it just continues to play the game. What am I doing wrong? I am using and testing in Unity 2D. There are no errors and all the prints are visible.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Normal_Car : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int counter = 0;

    public Vector3 finalPos = new Vector3(0.00f,0.00f,0.00f);

    public Transform t;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        t.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print("Frame: " + counter.ToString());
        counter += 1;
        t.position += finalPos;
        if(counter >= 140)
        {
            Application.Quit();
            print("Quit!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Your build crashes? Shows errors? It does something else? It does nothing? Is the print output visible? Are you testing this inside the editor or in a build?

Comment: Your edit only adresses part of my questions. Where are you testing this? Are the print outputs visible? Are there any errors?

Comment: I am testing in Unity and there are no errors. All the prints are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html) for `Application.Quit` it starts by saying this:

> Quits the player application. Shut down the running application. The Application.Quit call is ignored in the Editor.

`Application.Quit` does nothing if you test inside the editor.

Comment: Okay, then is there any other way to text this without having to export something every time? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Test what? Test the `Application.Quit()` implementation? Is it not enough to for an example debug log something before calling `Application.Quit()` and verifying that it is output correctly? Also a quick googling of "unity stop editor" yields this among other things: https://answers.unity.com/questions/161858/startstop-playmode-from-editor-script.html if you want to stop the editor playing instead.

Comment: Yes, I meant to stop the editor as a place holder for testing my game.

Answer (score 2):

There were some comments here but no actual solution.
The answers of course exist by searching but not in this post.

The ability to exit the game in BOTH standalone and editor mode is important for testing menus and other factors. Here is an example:

```
public void ExitGame()
{
    SaveGame();

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE
        Application.Quit();
    #endif

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #endif
}

private void SaveGame()
{
    Debug.Log("Saving Game...");
}
```

Hopefully this clarifies things a bit

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this.Quit();
That might just be in WinForms though :)

Comment: "I think" — did you try researching or testing this suggestion to have more confidence that it applies in Unity?

Comment: @DMGregory I was following a tutorial for WinForms and he said 'do this.quit(); to make a quit button'

Comment: Is this question about WinForms?

Comment: No, but WinForms uses C# and unity uses that too.

Comment: `this` refers the the current object, the object of the class that owns the code where `this` is written. `this` will mean a different object depending on where it is written. You might want to read up a bit more on the topic.

Comment: Your right, sorry mate

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Just make sure your answers actually address the Question asked :)

Comment: Alright! Thanks!